# php paragraph decoding to original text

Tags: php, string, decoding

I am trying to decode a paragraph using the PHP code below:

```
$str="Campaign+Description%0D%0A%0D%0AOperators+AIS+%0D%0A%0D%0ANot+allowed%3A%0D%0AIncent%0D%0AContent+Lock%0D%0ASMS+%26+Email%0D%0AVirtual+currency%0D%0AWiFi";
html_entity_decode(htmlentities($str));
```

However, I am not able to decode it and get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

This is a url encoded string so you need to use the `urldecode()` function on this, not `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: I used  urldecode(htmlentities($str)) still getting same string displayed.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The string which you are tying to decode is url, not textual paragraph. So use **urldecode()** function.

Try below code :

```
$str="Campaign+Description%0D%0A%0D%0AOperators+AIS+%0D%0A%0D%0ANot+allowed%3A%0D%0AIncent%0D%0AContent+Lock%0D%0ASMS+%26+Email%0D%0AVirtual+currency%0D%0AWiFi";
urldecode(htmlentities($str));
```

Comment: Thanks I got it, Thank you very much Manthan Dave